Conditional CellStyling in WPF DataGrid
The following code works as long as I only test one trigger. When I began adding single buttons into each cell, everything seemed fine. However, the issue arose when I added one cell with two buttons and unexpectedly, all other cells also received double buttons
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Signal" CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False" Width="80" MaxWidth="80"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowDoubleButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.3"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.BrowseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                                    Width="39" 
                                                                    Height="25"
                                                                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                                                    Background="LightGray">
                                                                <Image Source="\icons\addFolder.png" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                            </Button>
                                                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.BrowseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                                    Width="39"
                                                                    Height="25"
                                                                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                                                    Background="LightGray">
                                                                <Image Source="\icons\addFolder.png" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowDoubleButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.3"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.BrowseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                                Width="35"
                                                                Height="25"
                                                                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                                                Background="LightGray">
                                                            <Image Source="\icons\addFolder.png" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


Your problem is not clear. You are templating a column. The modifications of the trigger effects all cells of a column (every row). Do you want to apply the trigger to a single row?
